# BigQuery equivalent of FastExport

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, teradata, data-warehouse, fastexport

I have multiple uses cases of Teradata fast export to extract data for various reports & feed to some mainframe jobs (Binary data). 
In BigQuery I have a way to run  **bq extract **, however options are limited. I would like to know is there any equivalent utility for FastExport in BigQuery.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what features are missing to serve your use case?

Comment: @YunZhang I have some legacy job that sends data to TD , does heavy processing on Teradata and after that extracts the processed data (By combining other data in Datawarehouse)  back to the mainframe. This extracted file , depending on use case needs to be in Binary format, fixed-width, handle pact decimal, combining multiple binary extracted files into one. Is there a better way to feed processed data from BigQuery to MainFrame (like running a FastExport equivalent script for BQ), instead of doing custom code to handle all these.

Comment: I looked at FastExport documentation. It seems a proprietary scripting language made by TD to do complicated exporting job. The closest thing with BigQuery seems like to translate FastExport logic into BigQuery SQL or scripting and put all fields in place. Then manually write code to translate data table into the format MainFrame recognizes.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know is there any equivalent utility for FastExport in BigQuery

Yes. It is called [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/)

> > The BigQuery Storage API provides fast access to BigQuery managed storage by using an rpc-based protocol.

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail for pointing out to BQ Storage API. However, my requirement is more towards getting data in File that contains data in Binary Format and Fixwidth so a mainframe job can continue reading the file as is after a switch to BigQuery from TD.